# Getting a buffer into a stringstream in hex representation:

Tags: c++, stringstream

If I had a buffer like:

```
uint8_t buffer[32];
```

and it was filled up completely with values, how could I get it into a stringstream, in hexadecimal representation, with 0-padding on small values?

I tried:

```
std::stringstream ss;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    ss << std::hex << buffer[i];
}
```

but when I take the string out of the stringstream, I have an issue: bytes with values < 16 only take one character to represent, and I'd like them to be 0 padded.

For example if bytes 1 and 2 in the array were {32} {4} my stringstream would have:

```
204 instead of 2004
```

Can I apply formatting to the stringstream to add the 0-padding somehow?  I know I can do this with sprintf, but the streams already being used for a lot of information and it would be a great help to achieve this somehow.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(buffer[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Look at the stream modifiers:  `std::setw` and `std::setfill`. It will help you.

Comment: +1 since this was the first answer and said similar things :)

Comment: Quick correction, I believe Thomas meant `std::setfill`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
  ss << std::format("{:02}", buffer[i]);
}
```

Until `std::format` is widely available you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `join` function that makes this even easier ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K75vr3oee)):

```
std::string s = fmt::format("{:02}", fmt::join(buffer, ""));
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.