# Is casting uint8_t to signed int at least sometimes incorrect?

Tags: c++, casting, int, unsigned

While reading the answer to the following question

[Getting a buffer into a stringstream in hex representation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639656/getting-a-buffer-into-a-stringstream-in-hex-representation)

I did not understand why there is a necessity to cast `uint8_t` to `unsigned` (or, as written in comments, even to `unsigned char` before that), while casting just to `int` is incorrect.

As I understand, no conversions at all would lead to interpreting `uint8_t` as an underlying type which can (must?) be some of 3 `char` variations and thus printing it as a character.

But what's wrong with casting to `int`? Any `uint8_t` value should always fit in `int`, so the conversion seems to be straightforward. Why sign-extension would make the code incorrect (mentioned in comments)?

**UPD**:

Just for reference, I figured what was talked about in the question I referred to is a case for `signed char`:

```
signed char num = -1;
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(num));
```

This would be written as more than 2 `f`s in absence of the second cast.

The point about 2's complement system seems to be incorrect though, as an integral conversion should apply to convert -1 to `unsigned <smth>`, and it adheres to the 2's complement system (i.e. when converting to e.g. `uint8_t` the result should always be 255 and thus be printed as `0xff`, even having a different bit pattern).

Comment: Are you talking about casting between pointer types or casting between values of those types?

Comment: The answers and comments are probably just being defensive in cases where the type of the buffer might be `char` (or some other non-`unsigned` type). You can safely cast the `uint8_t` to `int` without sign-extension issues.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux conversion between the values of those types themselves (as it is done in the answer to the question I mentioned, i.e. conversion from `uint8_t` to `int` (`unsigned`))

Comment: @Cornstalks The comments are just plain wrong. If the type of the buffer is `char`, then casting it to either `int` or `unsigned int` is incorrect if you wish to get a result in `0`..`UCHAR_MAX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that casting `uint8_t` to `int` will produce the exact same value as casting `uint8_t` to `unsigned int`. A simple loop to test all possible values of `uint8_t`, 0 ... 255, will confirm that the generated strings are 100% identical, and given that all implementations must support `int` values even higher than 255, there is no chance of some obscure implementation where limited range of `int` might cause problems.

Comment: And you can even do that **conversion** without a **cast**.

Comment: @PeteBecker In general, yes. In the context of the question, no. When there are several function (or in this case operator) overloads, you may need casts to force a particular overload to be picked even if the conversion that you're performing is one that can be performed implicitly in other contexts.